# get JSON array data

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have a JSON array. Like This :

```
[
  {
    "id": 3110,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Dr Abul Khair"
    },
    "medilink_degree": "Associate Professor
  }
]
```

By using retrofit, I can get `id` and `medilink_degree` in my android application. But the `title` can not be retrieved because of its format like this :

```
"title":{"rendered":"Dr Abul Khair"}
```

I am getting data by using `@SerializedName("id")`

But, how can I get the title? I used  `@SerializedName("title.rendered")`. It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below Model Classes for getting data from API.

```
public class Title {

@SerializedName("rendered")
@Expose
private String rendered;

public String getRendered() {
return rendered;
}

public void setRendered(String rendered) {
   this.rendered = rendered;
}

}

public class User {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private Title title;
@SerializedName("medilink_degree")
@Expose
private String medilinkDegree;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Title getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(Title title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getMedilinkDegree() {
return medilinkDegree;
}

public void setMedilinkDegree(String medilinkDegree) {
this.medilinkDegree = medilinkDegree;
}

}
```

You can see the below link how to use the retrofit to Get data by a Model Class.

https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23

Comment: then which method I have to call in my RecyclerView Adapter to get data. Is it getRendered() or getTitle()

Comment: You have to use the getTitle() and from the method you can get getRendered(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate class named Title and in that you have to define rendered variable. Here is the code for reference.

```
    public class DoctorProfile {

        @SerializedName("id")
        private int id;
        @SerializedName("title")
        private Title title;
        @SerializedName("medilink_degree")        
        private String medilinkDegree;

     //getter-setter methods   

       public static class Title {
           @SerializeName("rendered")
           private String rendered;
           //getter-setter method
        }
    }
```

Comment: then which method I have to call in my RecyclerView Adapter to get data. Is it getRendered() or getTitle()

Comment: you have to first call getTitle(), it returns the Title object and with the help of this object you can call the getRendered() which is inside the Title class.

Comment: Got it. Thank You Very much

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.product;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CategoryResponse {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private Title title;
@SerializedName("medilink_degree")
@Expose
private String medilinkDegree;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Title getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(Title title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getMedilinkDegree() {
return medilinkDegree;
}

public void setMedilinkDegree(String medilinkDegree) {
this.medilinkDegree = medilinkDegree;
}

}
```

You can get a title like below:

```
CategoryResponse categoryResponse= assign your reponse;
String title = categoryResponse.getTitle().getRendered();
Log.e("Title: ", ""+ title);
```

You can create your response pojo from [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)